Remove shared NAS drive from MacBook Air
I set up a share on to a NAS on our home LAN on my wife's MacBook Air using the admin account of the NAS.  This gives her access to every folder on the NAS as this screenshot shows:

I just want her to have access to her files which are below the /homes/her_name folder.  I tried disconnecting the locations using the button in the top RH corner but the locations are reconnected pretty quickly.  I looked for an Eject button/menu item but can't find one.  I think I need to log out as the admin user and re-login using her credentials on the NAS but don't know how to do this (I'm not a Mac user - I know - shame on me ...).  Or do I need to do something else?  Thanks for your suggestions in advance.

How did you connect to the NAS? Also, you need to create a user account for your wife on the NAS with access only to her home share (and any others she might need to access).

Sorry, can't remember what I did - it was a over a year ago.  She already has an account on the NAS which (I think ...) only gives access to her home folder and sub-folder

The strange thing is that you don’t have eject icons in the location bar at left. You could try to remove the NAS login credentials from Keychain, this should at least trigger the login dialog again.

I looked in Settings | Passwords on her MacBook and there is no entry corresponding to the admin password for the NAS.  I clicked on the /homes folder and the Eject button appeared so I ejected the Network drive but 10 secs later, she was logged back on as admin

"Keychain Access", use Spotlight (Cmd-Space) to start it. Also, please open Terminal (again, search via Spotlight), enter mount | grep ' /Volumes' and copy/paste the result into the question with an edit.

Found the admin references in Keychain and have deleted them.  Added the result of the grep in the question (same result before and after deletion).  Logged into the NAS using her u/n and she still has access to all folders so think this must be an issue with file permissions on the NAS (QNAP).

The edit didn’t work. With the account of your wife, do you just see the top folders in the screenshot or can you open them?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
